# Split string to array using delimiter, getting second to last element in SELECT Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Heads!

In my database, I have a column that contains the following data (examples):

```
H-01-01-02-01

BLE-01-03-01

H-02-05-1.1-03
```

The task is to get the second to last element of the array if you would split that using the "-" character. The strings are of different length.

So this would be the result using the above mentioned data:

```
02

03

1.1
```

Basically I'm searching for an equivalent of the following ruby-statement for use in a Select-Statement in SQL-Server:

```
"BLE-01-03-01".split("-")[-2]
```

Is this possible in any way in SQL Server? After spending some time searching for a solution, I only found ones that work for the last or first element.

Thanks very much for any clues or solutions!

PS: Version of SQL Server is Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: If you only want the second to last, you might get better performance using `charindex`, `substring` and `reverse` instead of actually splitting the string.

Comment: Substring is not really possible because the strings are of different length. I also edited the post to include the SQL Server Version.

Comment: That's why you need `charindex`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can try this:.

--A mockup table with some test data to simulate your issue

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, YourColumn VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES 
 ('H-01-01-02-01') 
,('BLE-01-03-01')
,('H-02-05-1.1-03');
```

--The query

```
SELECT CastedToXml.value('/x[sql:column("CountOfFragments")-1][1]','nvarchar(10)') AS TheWantedFragment
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t.YourColumn,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML))A(CastedToXml)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CastedToXml.value('count(/x)','int')) B(CountOfFragments);
```

The idea in short:

The first `APPLY` will transform the string to a XML like this

```
<x>H</x>
<x>01</x>
<x>01</x>
<x>02</x>
<x>01</x>
```

The second `APPLY` will xquery into this XML to get the count of fragments. As `APPLY` will add this as a column to the result set, we can use the value using `sql:column()` to get the wanted fragment by its position.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment - using `charindex` with `reverse`.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Col Varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @T (Col) VALUES
('H-01-01-02-01'),
('BLE-01-03-01'),
('H-02-05-1.1-03');
```

The query:

```
SELECT  Col, 
        LEFT(RIGHT(Col, AlmostLastDelimiter-1), AlmostLastDelimiter - LastDelimiter - 1) As SecondToLast
FROM @T 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CharIndex('-', Reverse(Col)) As LastDelimiter) As A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CharIndex('-', Reverse(Col), LastDelimiter+1) As AlmostLastDelimiter) As B
```

Results:

```
Col             SecondToLast
H-01-01-02-01   02
BLE-01-03-01    03
H-02-05-1.1-03  1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Zohar's solution, but using CTEs instead of `CROSS APPLY` to prevent redundancy.  I personally find this easier to follow, as you can see what happens in each step.  Doesn't make it a better solution though ;)

```
DECLARE @strings TABLE (data VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @strings VALUES ('H-01-01-02-01') , ('BLE-01-03-01'), ('H-02-05-1.1-03');
WITH rev AS (
    SELECT
        data,
        REVERSE(data) AS reversed
    FROM
        @strings),
first_hyphen AS (
    SELECT
        data,
        reversed,
        CHARINDEX('-', reversed) + 1 AS first_pos
    FROM
        rev),
second_hyphen AS (
    SELECT
        data,
        reversed,
        first_pos,
        CHARINDEX('-', reversed, first_pos) AS second_pos
    FROM
        first_hyphen)
SELECT
    data,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reversed, first_pos, second_pos - first_pos)) AS result
FROM
    second_hyphen;
```

Results:

```
data            result
H-01-01-02-01   02
BLE-01-03-01    03
H-02-05-1.1-03  1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare @input NVARCHAR(100)
declare @dlmt NVARCHAR(3);
declare @pos INT = 2
SET @input=REVERSE(N'H-02-05-1.1-03');
SET @dlmt=N'-';
SELECT 
    CAST(N'<x>' 
    + REPLACE(
                (SELECT REPLACE(@input,@dlmt,'#DLMT#') AS [*] FOR XML PATH(''))
                    ,N'#DLMT#',N'</x><x>'
              ) + N'</x>' AS XML).value('/x[sql:variable("@pos")][1]','nvarchar(max)');
```